# In a proof what does showing LHS "=" RHS really mean?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, proof-writing

When showing: If (conditions) then ( A = B ). Is it necessary to start from the conditions, begin from ( A ) and end up at ( B ) AND then also begin from ( B ) and end up at ( A )?

I ask this due to noticing 2 situations which seem similar, but seem to have different logical arguments:

For example in showing set ( X ) = set ( Y ), I must show ( X ) is contained in ( Y ) AND ( Y ) is contained in ( X ).

But to show that, for example, $ \lim_{{n \to \infty}} a_n + \lim_{{n \to \infty}} b_n = \lim_{{n \to \infty}} (a_n + b_n) $, I pick a side (most often the left) and work towards a form representing the right. But I don't then also show from starting from the right-hand side that I can obtain the left.

This is making me question the proofs I have completed before and if I have left all of them half-complete. Does what "=" requires change in every context?

Comment: For your example, you just need to start at the left.  Though be careful, that equality is masking the more precise statement: *if* both terms on the left actually exist, then the term on the right exists AND the value on the LHS equals the value on the RHS.  But an analogy with your set equality statement is that to prove that $a=b$, you might show that $a\leq b$ and $b\leq a$.  It's not a matter of starting from one side and getting to the other side, though, you can start anywhere as long as you have a clear and logical argument.

Comment: Why just the left? Also say I started from the right, (reversing the steps I took from the left) then |(a_i +b_i)-c|=|(a_i-a) +(b_i-b)| (splitting c into a + b) <= |(a_i-a)| +|(b_i-b)| < epsilon/2 + epsilon/2 (rescaling epsilon from using the existence of the limits) = epsilon. But this doesn't show the equality really right? As I knew |(a_i-a)| +|(b_i-b)| < epsilon from the condition that both terms actually exist?

Comment: This all comes down to the distinction between equivalence relations and slack ordering relations, and the implications thereof for bidirectional inference.

Comment: Why just the left? Because (for your specific example), if the left hand side exists, then the right hand side exists, but the reverse is NOT true.  For example, if $a_n=n, b_n=-n$.  Getting equality is a consequence of showing existence, most likely.

Comment: Hi Aaron, thank you for your time. So the statement I gave does not make sense starting from the right, as it is false and is not what the statement is saying? So in certain statements are designed for a proof to start from one side only? Could you explain what you mean by "Getting equality is a consequence of showing existence" in this context?

Comment: It's not really about starting from a side.  That is only one of many different ways to show that two things are equal.  It all depends on context.  For example, you can prove that two expressions are equal by showing that they both describe different ways of counting something.  There, you wouldn't be starting from either side. I think you are looking for a narrow description of "this is how it is done" which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to show $A=B$, you start with your assumptions, then you make logical statements (be it a long string of equal signs, or a bunch of sentences or whatever else) and then you conclude.

When dealing with numerical quantities (e.g to show that $1+\tan^2x=\sec^2x$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $x$ is not an integer multiple of $\pi/2$), the way the proof usually unfolds is as you said: start from one side, do some manipulations (i.e more equations) and then use things you already know, and then conclude. Or, you can start from something you already know to be true, and then make logical steps from there. For instance, for the above trigonometric example, we can phrase a proof as follows:

> **Proof 1**
>
> For any real number $x$ which is not an integer multiple of $\pi/2$, we have
> \begin{align}
> 1+\tan^2x&=1+\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}\\
> &=\frac{\cos^2x+\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}\\
> &=\frac{1}{\cos^2x}\\
> &=\sec^2x
> \end{align}
> (The condition of not being an integer multiple of $\pi/2$ being used to ensure no division by zero occurs, and the rest is definition or the basic trigonometric identity)

This is an example of a proof of a statement using a bunch of successive equal signs. Another way of presenting the proof is:

> **Proof 2(i)**
>
> For all $x\in\Bbb{R}$, we know that $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$. So, if $x$ is in addition not an integer multiple of $\pi/2$, we can divide both sides of this equation by $\cos^2x$ to get $\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}+1=\frac{1}{\cos^2x}$, or using basic definitions, $\tan^2x+1=\sec^2x$, i.e $1+\tan^2x=\sec^2x$.

Or in a more symbolic manner,

> **Proof 2(ii)**
>
> For every $x\in\Bbb{R}$ which is not an integer multiple of $\pi/2$,
> \begin{align}
> \sin^2x+\cos^2x=1&\implies \frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}+1=\frac{1}{\cos^2x}\implies \tan^2x+1=\sec^2x.
> \end{align}
> (And ideally, I would prefer some form of concluding statement, like: Since the antecedent is true, it follows the consequent is true. But of course, this is a trivial enough example that I wouldn’t really bother).

In high school, your teachers will abhor proof (2i) and possibly even (2ii) (mine certainly did), but it’s not because the proof is wrong (it is perfectly correct), but rather because (for one, they need to use more mental effort to read wha you’re actually doing) students who aren’t careful will definitely mess up and give logically incorrect proofs, hence why they would greatly prefer the more structured ‘show the LHS equals RHS’ approach as in the ‘first proof’ so as to minimize student mistakes. So, it is a pedagogically-motivated effort not a purely logical one (we can debate the merits of this decision, but that’s besides the point here).

However, notice that the point here is not about LHS=RHS or RHS=LHS or manipulating both and meeting halfway, or showing that “for all $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2>0$, $\text{LHS}<\text{RHS}+\epsilon_1$ and $\text{RHS}<\text{LHS}+\epsilon_2$” or any other variant; in fact, as you get deeper into math the level of sophistication, and techniques developed for showing two things are equal grows ***A LOT***. The most important thing is to give a logically correct argument, making explicit use of your assumptions (e.g $x$ not an integer multiple of $\pi/2$), any theorems you already know (e.g the trigonometric identity $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$, and all the rules of arithmetic) and definitions (e.g of $\tan,\sec$). Secondary (but still important of course) is presenting/communicating that logic in a clear manner.

So, to directly answer your question of

> “This is making me question the proofs I have completed before and if I have left all of them half-complete.”

I’d say no, your proofs are not half-complete (assuming the questions are ‘like’ the one I posed above).

Regarding equality of sets $X=Y$, the reason you show $X$ is contained in $Y$ and $Y$ is contained in $X$ is because that’s what the **definition** of set equality is. So, typically, a proof of showing $X=Y$ as sets will schematically look like:

> Let $x\in X$. Then [blablablablabla, possibly paragraphs or even hundreds of pages of stuff]. Therefore, $x\in Y$. This shows $X\subset Y$.
>
> Conversely, let $y\in Y$. Then [blablabla], and hence $y\in X$, which proves $Y\subset X$ and thus $X=Y$.

Or, sometimes if things are easy enough, you can simply phrase it along the lines of:

> For all $x$, we have that
> \begin{align}
> x\in X&\iff \cdots\\
> &\iff \cdots\\
> &\iff \cdots\\
> &\iff x\in Y
> \end{align}
> Therefore, $X=Y$.

Notice that this line of reasoning (while it looks different to the one above) is logically doing the same thing: we are using equivalences $\iff$ throughout, so both directions are being addressed ‘simultaneously’. Once again, what is most important is that you logically get from one step to the next (whether it is in the form of a sentence, an equation, a very nicely labelled picture + explanation or whatever else). Secondary is the issue of how to present all that information.

---

Finally, let me address your other comment of

> But I don't then also show from starting from the right-hand side that I can obtain the left.

It doesn’t matter. Looking back at the trigonometric identity above, almost everyone is ‘trained’ to read it left to right and the proof would indeed be ‘awkward’ (psychologically) if I wrote it as

> For any $x\in\Bbb{R}$ which is not an integer multiple of $\pi/2$,
> \begin{align}
> \sec^2x=\frac{1}{\cos^2x}=\frac{\sin^2x+\cos^2x}{\cos^2x}=\tan^2x+1.
> \end{align}

This is of course perfectly correct, but very few of us (when first learning trigonometry) would think in this way going left-to-right because we’re not used to ‘complicating’ things by writing $1=\sin^2x+\cos^2x$, but we’re more than happy to ‘simplify’ $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$, even though both are logically equivalent. This is just how our brain works, and doesn’t take away from the correctness of any of the proofs I’ve shown here.

Fun fact: expressing $1$ in a clever way, or adding $0$ to both sides of an equation in a clever way of anything else is well… clever… and there are fantastic results out there. There have been numerous occasions where I just said ‘wow how did ___ come up with that’ or ‘there’s no way I would come up with that (but now that I see it, I can’t forget it)’. In fact one of my professors said that (in the context of a *Harmonic Analysis* course) ‘adding zero in the right way can make you very famous’.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your explanation! If you would not mind, am I correct in saying generally, I have to know well,what equality means between the 2 objects (whether they be sets, functions or limits (in which case it really means $ \lim_{{n \to \infty}} a_n + \lim_{{n \to \infty}} b_n = (a+b) =\lim_{{n \to \infty}} (a_n + b_n) $)) instead of thinking of equality as "if and only if". Proving an equality as per its definition, say left to right does not matter as long as I take logically valid steps to the end, I can prove right to left but what I have already done has alreadycompleted the task.

Comment: Yes that’s right

Answer (score 0):

LHS = RHS means that LHS and RHS are the same mathematical object. They are mathematically indistinguishable. The difference in the proofs comes from the tools at our disposal to manipulate different kinds of objects. For example with numbers we can use known properties such as $(x+y)^2 = x^2+ 2 x y + y^2$ and with such properties, "begin from $A$" and "end up at $B$". Sets obey different rules, for example if we now that $X\subset A$, we can use that $A = A\cup X$ in our proofs. Every kind of object belongs to its own ecosystem of known properties.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time in answering. Am I correct in saying  that with different mathematical objects (I am not formally aware of the categories but) like numbers, sets, functions each have known definitions, and methods that only make sense in the context of them and obey rules. Given these properties you need to manipulate based on these and this results in proofs that appear different but are logically valid in their own world(category of numbers, sets, functions etc.)?

Comment: Yes I suppose you are correct, but keep in mind that these interpretations are subjective. Think about how to prove that the sum of the angles of a triangle is equal to $\pi$. The main questions are 'what is an angle, a triangle?', 'how are the three angles of a triangle defined?', 'How do you add angles?' etc.

Answer (score 0):

When in some algebraic proof you go through a succession of steps $A = …. = B$, you will have shown, by transitivity of $=$, that $A = B$.

But by symmetry of $=$, that immediately means $B =A$. Indeed, you could simply reverse all this steps to produce $B = … = A$, but there is no need for that.

Ok, you ask, but why does it seem different for sets?

Well, it is ‘t.

Sure enough, it is true that when working with sets, you often end up doing two proofs when trying to show $A =B$: one that shows that $ A \subseteq B$, and one that shows $ B \subseteq A$.

However, note how different this is from the situation above: with the first proof I do not show $A = B$, but  rather I show $ A \subseteq B$, and since $\subseteq$ is *not* symmetrical, I cannot infer that $ B \subseteq A$, so the latter will require a separate, second proof.

Indeed, in these two proofs I do not go through a succession of equalities $A = …. = B$. Rather, you go through a succession of *implications*: $x \in A \Rightarrow … \Rightarrow x \in B$. And again, since implication is not symmetric,  this is not something that is reversible.

Ok … so then why did I just say that sets things are not any different? Well, suppose I have shown some elementary set-theoretic results like $(A^C)^C = A$, $A \cup B = B \cup A$, $A \cup (B \cap C) = (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$, etc, etc. Once I have those, I can show that for any sets $A, B$, and $C$, it is true that $(A^C \cup B) \cap A = A \cap B$:

$(A^C \cup B) \cap A = A \cap (A^C \cup B) = (A \cap A^C) \cup (A \cap B) = \emptyset \cup (A \cap B) = A \cap B$

And note: *now* we are back at a process of showing successive *equalities*, meaning that we have at the same time shown that $A \cap B = (A^C \cup B) \cap A$ without having to do a second proof.

In sum, it *looks* like proofs involving sets behave differently than for, say, numbers, but that is really not the case.

But what should also be clear from this is that you always need to pay attention to and understand what exactly it is that you are showing.

Comment: Thank you for your time! It helped, especially on explicitly explaining the symmetricity of implication and containments.

Comment: @Hpinard33 I am glad it was useful! You’re welcome :)